# How to know if date has change in datepicker jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a date picker tied in with a calendar icon. when you click it and select a date, it populates a readonly text field. What i'm trying to do is i want to know when and if the date has changed.

I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#individual_due_date_1").change(function(){
    alert("hello");
  });
}
```

but the code never gets ran. is there another way of doing this? or am i doing this wrong? 
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us how you apply the date picker, and which of the many datepicker libraries you use?

Answer (score 1):

The `change` event is not fired when the value changes dynamically, but the datepicker has an `onSelect` event you should be using.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        onSelect: function() {
            // datepicker changed
        }
    });
});
```